# Why doesn't my game start in landscape mode?

Tags: camera, andengine, aspect-ratio

I want my game to run on all Android devices in `LANDSCAPE_FIXED` mode, but this mode works only for some screen resolutions. `PORTRAIT_FIXED` works well for all devices. I'm testing this on and emulator.

How can I achieve this? Here's my camera/engine initialization code:

```
public EngineOptions onCreateEngineOptions() {
    cw=480;
    ch=320;
    camera = new Camera(0, 0, cw, ch);
    EngineOptions engineOptions = new EngineOptions(
        true,
        ScreenOrientation.LANDSCAPE_FIXED,
        new RatioResolutionPolicy(cw, ch),
        this.camera
    );
    engineOptions.setWakeLockOptions(WakeLockOptions.SCREEN_ON);
    return engineOptions;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using the `android:screenOrientation="landscape"` option in the manifest file's activity tag.